# JQuery SQL query builder

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build a simple SQL query builder

I have a table with the below columns:

> |  Table | Field  |  Expression   |  Order By |  Alias

My code trying to construct the query:

```
    /* Build SQL string */ 
$(".ConvertSQL").click(function () {

    /* Construct an array of the tables and field names (used to build the SELECT query) */
    var query = $('.TableQuery > tbody > tr').map(function () {
    var $td = $(this).children('td');           
    return `[${$td.eq(0).html()}].[${$td.eq(1).html()}]`; }).get().join(', ');

    var queryOrderBy = $('.TableQuery > tbody > tr').map(function () {
    var $td1 = $(this).children('td');
    return `[${$td1.eq(0).html()}].[${$td1.eq(1).html()}] ${$td1.eq(3).html()}`; }).get().join(', ');

    var queryAlias = $('.TableQuery > tbody > tr').map(function () {
    var $td2 = $(this).children('td');
    return `${$td2.eq(2).html()}([${$td2.eq(0).html()}].[${$td2.eq(1).html()}]) AS ${$td2.eq(4).html()}`;  }).get().join(', ');



    /* Piece together the SQL query */
    var PartOne = (`SELECT ${queryAlias} FROM [`);
    var fromTable = $('.TableQuery tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1)').text();
    var Order = (`] ORDER BY ${queryOrderBy}`);

    /* Show the SQL in the textarea */
    $("#SQLstring").val(PartOne + fromTable + Order ); 

});
```

Im aware I may very well be going down a rabbit hole and potentially taking the wrong approach to work this.

Anyhow, at the moment if I generate a straight forward SELECT query then the code actually works fine.

However, it goes wrong when an expression is added - e,g: SUM()

Based on my code if they added a SUM if would show like this...

```
SELECT  count([TestTable].[Total]) AS Test, ([TestTable].[User]) AS [Test] FROM [TestTable]
```

As you can see the below section wont work because of the brackets around it

> ([Reporting].[User])

- ADDED *
  Updated my SQL example to prevent any confusion of needing joins

Comment: Will this be running on a webpage? I think there are security concerns with generating SQL that will describe the structure of your database to a potential hacker. Moreover, if the SQL will be sent to your backend for queries to your database, the SQL may be possible to alter to inject a malicious behavior (`DELETE, DROP` etc).

Comment: Thanks for the reply - Its more of an internal page for us to use